# Why $z^k e^{lz}$ is solution for $\frac{d^n}{dz^n}(\frac{d}{dz} - 1)^n \dots (\frac{d}{dz} - n + 1)^n y = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Consider functions $z^k e^{lz}$. The lemma in my book sais that these functions are solutions (at $z = 0$) of $\frac{d^n}{dz^n}(\frac{d}{dz} -  1)^n \dots (\frac{d}{dz} - n + 1)^n y(z) = 0$? And I don't understand why it should be ?

Comment: Any constrains on $k,l$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: 
The general solution of 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( \frac{d}{dz} -l \right) y=0 
\end{eqnarray*}
is $y=Ae^{lz}$ (where $A$ is an arbitrary constant) and 
the general solution of 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( \frac{d}{dz} -l \right)^n y=0 
\end{eqnarray*}
is $y=f(z)e^{lz}$ where $f(z)$ is an arbitrary polynomial of degree less than $n$.